# Shell - remove space between characters in all fields in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, field, space

I have a file like this (with tab delimiter) :

```
1    6989    A A    G G    C A
1    6987    G A    C G    G C
```

I want to remove spaces in all fields between letters starting at the 3rd column to have :

```
1    6989    AA    GG    CA
1    6987    GA    CG    GC
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your example that you can just remove all spaces, full stop:

```
ex -sc '%s/ //g|x' file
```

Or:

```
sed 's/ //g' file
```

Or:

```
awk '{gsub(" ", "")} 1' file
```

Comment: `tr -d ' ' < file`